# Commutativity and direct sum decomposition of Lie Algebras

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

G is a connected compact Lie group and G' is a dense Lie subgroup of G, they correspond to Lie Algebras $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{g'}$. Now we have questions:

(I)Can we proof $\mathfrak{g'}$ is an ideal of $\mathfrak{g}$?

(II)How to proof $\mathfrak{g'}$ is communicative if and only if $\mathfrak{g}$ is communicative?

(III)Can we proof there is a communicative ideal $\mathfrak{g''}$ of $\mathfrak{g}$ such that we have a direct sum decomposition of Lie Algebra: $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{g'}+\mathfrak{g''} $?

Can we proof G'=G? I do not know how to proof it so I want too see a full proof.

Comment: If it is dense, shouldn't it equal the entire Lie group, if it is itself a Lie group?

Comment: I am not sure, can you give me a short proof or a reference about this conclusion？